# Page load timer?

Tags: php, pages, performance

Ok, so I'm confused as to what's going on here... I've been trying for hours now to get a relatively accurate page load timer setup on my WordPress site, but nothing is working like it's supposed to.

I've added this code to my theme's header.php file as the very first block of code:

```
<?php
  $exectime = microtime();
  $exectime = explode(" ",$exectime);
  $exectime = $exectime[1] + $exectime[0];
  $starttime = $exectime; 
?>
```

and then I added this block of code as the very last thing in my theme's footer.php file:

```
<?php
  $exectime = microtime();
  $exectime = explode(" ",$exectime);
  $exectime = $exectime[1] + $exectime[0];
  $endtime = $exectime;
  $totaltime = ($endtime - $starttime);
  echo '<!-- page rendered in '.$totaltime.' seconds -->';
?>
```

but rather than getting a somewhat accurate representation of how long it took the page to load, I'm getting these gargantuan numbers that I know aren't even close to accurate...

Here's one example result:

```
  </body> 
</html>
<!-- page rendered in 1321818086.6252 seconds -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$starttime` is undefined in your footer, so you're subtracting nothing from endtime. declare `global $starttime` first and it'll work.

that said, it won't be a very accurate indicator of rendering time, since most of the work WordPress does happens before you ever reach the template and start your timer. There's already a built-in timer that starts when WP is first loaded, you can print the output with the [timer_stop](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/timer_stop) function.

Comment: Ok, declaring $starttime as global didn't do the trick... and I was under the impression that timer_stop() was simply the time it took to execute the queries, not actually load the page... However, I think I may be confusing server processing time for front-end display time... So I guess I'll just stick with timer_stop() for now and be done with it.

Comment: declare it as global in header before you use it. `timer_stop` is total execution time, queries and page rendering. no PHP-based timer will be able to start before your server responds to a request and starts up PHP, it's accurate within it's own scope of awareness, but it can't possibly account for server response times and network latency.

Comment: I see... I guess that's where I was getting confused. I know nothing can account for network latency, but surely there's gotta be a way to account for server response times? (even if not in php)

Comment: @Nero_DCLXVI I use the [network panel](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/network.html) in webkit browsers to see response and load times. if it's not a local server it's always relative to my ISP and path to host, of course.